# Drupal 8 settings.yml file doesn't reflect changes

Tags: 8

So I'm trying to define some additional values in my settings.yml file, but none of my changes are reflected in the code. The config object has the same values in it. I've tried drush cr and other measures to clear the cache, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

yml files are just imported on module install time.

If you need runtime changes, during development, have a look at
https://www.drupal.org/project/config_devel